# How to parsimoniously refer to a data frame in RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I have a MySQL table that I am reading with the RMySQL package of R. I would like to be able to directly refer to the data frame stored in the table so I can seamlessly interact with it rather than having to execute RMySQL statement every time I want to do something. Is there a way to accomplish this? I tried:

```
data <- dbReadTable(conn = con, name = 'tablename')
```

For example, if I now want to check how many rows I have in this table I would run:

```
nrow(data)
```

Does this go through the database connection, or am I now storing the object "data" locally, defeating the whole purpose of using an external database?

Comment: How is this defeating the use of an external database? Could you please explain what you mean? As your question stands it does not make sense.

Comment: That downloads all the data into R. See the dplyr package for an alternative approach

Comment: Thank you @hadley. I am new at this, but I was certain I was already going down the wrong path :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data <- dbReadTable(conn = con, name = 'tablename')
```

This command downloads all the data into a local R dataframe (assuming you have enough RAM).  Any operations with data from that point forward do not require the SQL connection.